# Printing strings backwards from a linked list using iteration

Tags: c++, string, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I'm having trouble figuring out the code to make the pointer go backwards. I have a recursive function that already does this, however I'm having trouble creating an iterative function to do the same.

```
void print_list_backward(Node_ptr a_node)
{
  //base case. If a_node is Null, then simply return.
  if (a_node == NULL) {
    return;
    //recurisve case. cout the word follwed by the function call which prints 
    //the next word in the list
  } else {
    print_list_backward(a_node->ptr_to_next_node);
    cout << a_node->word << " ";
  }
}

void print_backward(Node_ptr a_node)
{
  while (a_node != NULL)
  {
    a_node = a_node->ptr_to_next_node;
    cout << a_node->word << " ";
  }
}
```

To be honest, my implementation of printing backwards in a linkedlist was kind of a fluke, but I just need help getting it to go backwards. I understand that the pointer moves from left to right, but I don't know how to get it to go from right to left.

My current output with `print_backward()` is

```
Input: The quick brown fox
Output: brown quick The
```

**EDIT** [Entire code w/ main](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd2915daa02144f49b118271ea86f1ac) This link has all the code and should hopefully add some perspective. The purpose of my question is finding a way to use iteration to print backwards in a linked-list, which is seemingly not possible?

The question for my project is

**Write and test an iterative​ (i.e. non-recursive) version of the function
print_list_backward named print_backward​()**

Comment: What have you observed with the debugger? Consider also [edit]ing in your `main` that shows the input and output also, just to make it easier for people to copy+paste into an editor to help.

Comment: Updated. And to answer your question, my program is running fine. No errors or anything

Comment: If your project does not restrict having a doubly linked list, why not modify your code to have pointers that also point backwards?

Comment: Because my professor said specifically "This project is not designed for doubly linked-lists or tail pointers" and not to modify any code excluding the fibonacci function, and the last 3 functions (print_list_forward, list_backward and backwards)

Answer (score 1):

When you have singly linked list, printing the list backwards is easiest with a recursive function. Using an iterative approach will work only if you are willing to store the pointers in another container, such as a stack, and then print the objects form the container. You end up iterating twice on the pointers.

```
void print_backward(Node_ptr a_node)
{
   std::stack<Node_ptr> nodes;
   while (a_node != NULL)
   {
      nodes.push(a_node);
      a_node = a_node->ptr_to_next_node;
   }

   while ( !nodes.empty() )
   {
      a_node = nodes.top();
      nodes.pop();
      cout << a_node->word << " ";
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand, its just that my project stated                                           **Write and test an iterative​ (i.e. non-recursive) version of the function print_list_backward named print_backward​()**

Comment: So while I agree that a recursive function would be easier, I had to follow the prompt. Also, I can't seem to use stack. Admittedly idk what that is.

Comment: @gf807, it is difficult to suggest anything without knowing all the constraints you are working with.

Comment: is it a requirement that you cannot use stack? (if you dunno what's that, just think you are putting the the linked list nodes in a `vector`, and iterate it in inverse order)

Answer (score 1):

I will use subfunctions:

```
void print_forward(Node_ptr a_node)
{
    while (a_node != nullptr) {
        std::cout << a_node->word << " ";
        a_node = a_node->ptr_to_next_node;
    }
}

Node_ptr reverse(Node_ptr a_node)
{
    Node_ptr prev = nullptr;
    while (a_node != nullptr) {
        Node_ptr next = a_node->ptr_to_next_node;
        a_node->ptr_to_next_node = prev;
        prev = a_node
        a_node = next;
    }
    return prev;
}

void print_backward(Node_ptr a_node)
{
    // Warning mutate list even if restored afterwards.
    a_node = reverse(a_node);
    print_forward(a_node);
    a_node = reverse(a_node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda funny, usually the tough part is the recursive implementation.

Alright, back to your problem. If you want to do it iteratively, the thing is,... you can't. At least, if you're using a singly-linked-list. As you said, pointers move from left to right. You can also store every single node in a stack and pop them while printing their words. But dude,... you don't wanna do that... Not because it is complicated because it's not at all, but because it looks awful.

One approach to your problem will be through using a doubly-linked-list, whereas you have total control over the directions of every node in your list. You can move from left to right as well as from right to left.

You can send the last node of your list as a argument to your function *print_backward* and then move from right to left.

Comment: Unfortunately the function I stated had to be used in an iterative fashion. In this situation recursion would be the goto, its just that I was told to specifically include an iterative function for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches that you can choose from:

### Reverse Copy

In brief, create a copy of your linked list which allow you to iterate in reverse order.  You may do it by a stack (as suggested by other answer), a new vector, or even a new linked list in reverse order.

This approach gives you both time and space complexity being `O(n)`

An example using vector (pseudo code):

```
vector<Node_ptr> temp_vector;
Node_ptr current_node = head;

while (current_node != nullptr) {
    temp_vector.push_back(current_node);
    current_node = current_node.next();
}

foreach node_ptr in (temp_vector.rbegin() to temp_vector.rend()) {
    print node_ptr;
}
```

### No copy

If you are not allowed to keep a copy of your linked list, then you may use this approach, which give you O(1) space complexity, but O(n^2) time complexity

pseudo-code:

```
Node_ptr current_node = get_last_node(head);

do {
    print current_node;
    current_node = find_previous(head, current_node);
} while (current_node != head)
```

Implementation of `get_last_node()` should be very straight-forward.  Leave it to you.

`find_previous` looks like this:

```
Node_ptr find_previous(Node_ptr head, Node_ptr node) {
    Node_ptr current_node = head;
    while (current_node->next() != node) { }
    return current_node;
}
```